# Save data value to SQL Server database over network or internet

Tags: c#, sql-server

I will like to try to build a Winform application with C# so I want to know how to save, update and delete data values to SQL Server over network or on the internet but not on local SQL Server database. Your help is certainly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords/)

Answer (score 0):

The update, delete or save of data values to a SQL server should be the same, you should just change the connection string and target the remote SQL server.

If you are using Entity Framework, you could change the connection string on your app.config.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Context" connectionString="Data Source={Ip remote server};Initial Catalog=Context;Integrated Security=True;User ID=sa;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you guys so much.